# How do I model my Rails application where users search for events and save the ones that interest them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model-view-controller

I am using three models:
 - users
 - events
 - user_events (the join table)

I feel like I do not need to save every search result because it would be unnecessary. The search will query two APIs and display maybe the top 10 results and display them to the user. The user then might be interested in one or two of these events and add them to a list of things that interest them, a bookmark, if you may. Bookmarks that are happening on the same day should then be grouped together for the users organizational purposes.

Should I make another **search** model along with a search controller? I'm fairly new to Rails and need some advice on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you make a bookmark or search class to store a search when a user wants to save it. Then you can construct a has_many relationship between a user and a bookmark. So a user will have many bookmarks. See this for more documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association